# removing css style for element by ID

Tags: jquery, css

how to disable style for element already has  styled with css by element name and I can't make the same same style by etering a class name in css just #ElementName which style attribute doesn't shown on html code?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Can you post a brief example of some code that exhibits the problem you are describing?

Comment: My best guess translation:
"How do I remove the a style from an element which has been styled in CSS (document?, style tag?).  However I isn't working when I set the style using the element's class.  It seems to only work when I use the element's id (eg #ElementName)."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try:

```
$("selector").removeAttr("style");
```

but my question is: why do you want to remove CSS styles? Usually this is a sign that you're not doing something in a good way. Like some will write code like this:

```
$("selector").hover(function() {
  $(this).css("background", "red");
}, function() {
  // ???
});
```

The problem of course is that you don't know what to set the background to in order to reset it to normal. That's why you should use classes:

```
div.highlight { background: red; }
```

with:

```
$("selector").hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass("highlight");
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass("highlight");
});
```

Problem solved.

So I can't comment on your approach because you haven't provided enough detail for that but in my experience questions like "how do I remove a style?" are a red flag.

Comment: Instead of setting style attribute with empty value, you can remove the style attribute itself by using removeAttr function:
http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/removeAttr#name

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable styles that are set, but you can override them. The `inherit` value can be used to restore the behaviour for styles that are inherited by default. Example:

```
div { color: red; }
div .exception { color: inherit; }
```

Any div element will get red text, except the ones with class="exception" which will inherit the text color from their parent.

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable a style, you can only override that style with specificity. If you absolutely have to, you can rely on the !important directive:

```
#el { background:red !important; }
```

Otherwise for god knows what if you can't/don't have access to CSS then you can do `$('#foo').css('background', 'red')` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the element style depending on the tag's standard via something like this:

```
$('#ElementName').css({
  'position': 'relative',
  'display': 'box',
  'with': 'auto',
  'height': 'auto',
  'color': '#FFFFFF'
});
```

You can rename the element id:

```
$('#ElementName').attr('id', 'ElementName2');
```

That's my best guesses.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue a couple weeks ago.  Every element has a default value. just override it to that default value.

ie.   width and height's default value is auto.  not all are auto though.  overflow's default is visible.